# VS Code Debug won't find Simulator; Simulator Debug opens browser instead

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

VS Code launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug iOS",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "ios"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to packager",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "attach"
        }
    ]
}
```

VS Code's "DEBUG AND RUN" choosing either Debug iOS or Attach to Packager won't do anything.
When I go to Simulator "Debug", it opens a browser page http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/ instead and I don't know how to step into breakpoints with that browser page.

How to use VS Code to debug my Simulator, please?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps

- Stop debug js remotely in your simulator
- Close the chrome debugger
- Choose Attach to package instead of Debug iOs
- Reload simulator
- Start debug js remotely

You can see the logs in vs code debug terminal

Comment: Doesn't work. 'attach to package' won't attach to anything, with no message. Debug terminal shows nothing.

Comment: "Established a connection with the Proxy (Packager) to the React Native application" are you getting this message in Debug console when you clicked Attach to packager ?

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall/reinstall ReactNativeTools in VSCode fixed this.